# File not being read

Tags: c, fopen

Disclaimer: some words in my code are in French.

When I compile my code there is no bug, but when I run it the only thing that appears is the sentence "Contenu du tableau avant le tri". I think the file I need to read (notes.txt) isn't being read. Anyone has any idea what the problem is? Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PERS 200



typedef struct
{
    int numero;
    float note;
    char nom, prenom;
}   donnees;

donnees tab[MAX_PERS];
int nbPers=0;



void lire(donnees tab[], int *n)
{
    FILE *aLire = fopen("notes.txt", "r");

    int nb=0;

    while(!feof(aLire))
    {
        fscanf(aLire, "%d%s%s%f\n", &tab[nb].numero, &tab[nb].nom, &tab[nb].prenom, &tab[nb].note);
        nb++;  
    }   
    fclose(aLire);
    *n = nb;   
}



void afficher(donnees tab[], int nb, char *quand)
{
    int i;

    printf("Contenu du tableau %s le tri\n\n", quand);

    for(i=0; i<nb; i++)
        printf( "%4d %15s %15s %2.2f\n", tab[i].numero, tab[i].nom, tab[i].prenom, tab[i].note);
}



void echanger (donnees *P1, donnees *P2)
{ 
    donnees tempo;

    tempo = *P1 ;
    *P1 = *P2;
    *P2 = tempo;
}



void  partitionner ( donnees tab[], int debut, int fin, int *P )
{ 
    int G = debut , D = fin  ;

    float Val_Pivot = tab[debut].note;

    while ( G <= D  &&  tab[G].note <= Val_Pivot) G++;

    while ( tab[D].note > Val_Pivot) D--;

        if ( G < D ) echanger(&tab[G], &tab[D]);

    while ( G <= D ) ;

        *P = D ;

        echanger (&tab[debut], &tab[D]);
}



void quickSort ( donnees tab[], int gauche, int droite )
{ 
    int indPivot ;

    if (droite > gauche)
        {
            partitionner ( tab, gauche, droite, &indPivot);
            quickSort ( tab, gauche, indPivot - 1 );
            quickSort ( tab, indPivot + 1, droite);
        }
}




int main()
{
    donnees tab[MAX_PERS];

    lire(tab, &nbPers);

    afficher(tab, nbPers, "avant");



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the file contents. For starters, check the return values of `fopen` and `fscanf`. Also, when a program doesn't work as expected what you should do is to debug it by running in a debugger or adding debug print statements. Have you done any of that and if so what did you find out about where things start going wrong?

Comment: If you are not sure if the file is actually being opened, try `if (!aLire) { /* error */ }` after `fopen` to check if `aLire` points to an address instead of NULL.

Comment: You could check for value of   nb at the end of function lire() , a simple printf to check if that's working as expected. Then check it again inside afficher(). Bon courage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: In your `partitionner` function, it seems unlikely that `while ( G <= D ) ;` is correct - this is an infinite loop (or a no-op). Does the `;` at the end belong.

Answer (score 0):

Verify `fopen` return result, as it returns `NULL` in case opening fail for some reason.

don't rely on `!feof` for detecting the end of the file, as your file can end partially, use `fscanf` return value instead (number of entry parsed/read )

then in your structure your are using `char` (one character) for name, where you should either have `char[some length]` or `char*`

```
int numero;
float  note;
char[MAX_LENGTH] nom;
char[MAX_LENGTH] prenom;
// assuming that field are separated by space
while(fscanf(
"%d %"MAX_LENGTH"s %"MAX_LENGTH"s %f",
&numero,
nom,
prenom,
&note) == 4) {
   // copy data in new row in array
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed `char nom` and `char prenom` to `char nom[MAX_LENGTH]` and  `char prenom[MAX_LENGTH]` and now it finally works. Had been stuck for two days, thank you!